# calloc created array is not acting as expected

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, calloc

I was bored and wanted to make a program to crash my computer :P. I would have it uselessly and redundantly allocate memory until the crash. The code I created so far is here:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, const char *argv)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        n++;
        int* buffer = (int*)malloc(n ^ n);
        int* buffer_buffer = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(buffer));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%p", &buffer);
            printf("\n");
            buffer_buffer[i] = (int)buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

The code works(it crashes the computer), but does not work as expected.I wanted to go more into the process of the how it worked and what exactly it was doing, so I set a few breakpoints and decided to step through it. I expected to see the `buffer_buffer` reallocated again and again containing `n` numbers of `buffer`, but it does not. Instead, my debugger shows that `buffer_buffer` contains a single value that sometimes will change, and a single value(the integer cast of `buffer` at least I hope) is logged every go round the loop. I was expecting the `buffer_buffer` to grow with `n` number of elements every time around the for loop comes around, but it only has one element. To visualize this, here is a screenshot of the debugger:

[image: Debugger]

Again I am somewhat tired and this is probably an issue with my loop logic. Does anyone know why my program is experiencing this unexpected behavior? I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio debugger

Comment: Sidenote: `^` is bitwise xor, so `malloc(n ^ n)` will allocate zero bytes of memory.

Comment: @sth technically it will *request* zero bytes; the implementation may either return a null pointer, or a non-null pointer which you aren't permitted to dereference. Some implementations might allocate memory anyway.

Comment: it's also unclear what you expect the body of the inner loop to do. `buffer` is never modified during this loop so `&buffer` and `(int)buffer` are the same every time you check them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your debugger doesn't know how big `buffer_buffer` is, since that variable is simply declared as being a pointer to an `int`. (That's not correctly typed; `buffer_buffer` is used to hold values of `buffer` which is an `int*`, so `buffer_buffer` must be an array of `int*`, which means that you should declare it as `int**`, i.e. a pointer to a sequence of `int*`.) One of the little challenges in debugging C programs is that the length of an array is not stored anywhere at all; you have to keep track of it yourself. So the debugger doesn't know either.

Also, `n^n` is 0, since `^` is the XOR operator. I don't know if that is what you intended.

---

(Actually, it's not quite true that the allocation size isn't stored anywhere. It might be, or some approximation to it might be. But it's stored in the internals of the memory allocation library, and there is no way to get at it. And anyway, it might not be correct, because the library sometimes allocates more than you asked for, and it only remembers what it allocated, not what you asked for.)

Comment: Whoops I saw something about `int**` once and had no idea what that was. As for the `^` I must have got mixed up. I was meaning to use exponentiation.

Comment: Also, would using a lower level debugger(at the asm or binary level) help with the debugger issue?

Comment: @James_Parsons You can type, `buffer_buffer,n` in the watch window to see the full contents if you're using MSVC (it looks from your screenshot like it's MSVC, can't tell for sure). Other debuggers might accept that format as well.

Comment: @James_Parsons: No. There is really no way to figure out how long the allocation is. Your program is expected to know. (And it does -- the array has `n` elements.) By the way, you know that you are allocating a new larger `buffer_buffer` every time through that loop, but never freeing the old ones, and then only setting one element in the new one? Perhaps you meant `realloc`, not `calloc`?

Comment: Oops yeah its MSVC should have specified that.

Comment: @James_Parsons: Also, C doesn't have an exponentiation operator. You can use the `pow` math library function, but because that function uses floating point and does not guarantee perfect accuracy, it's possible that truncating it back to an integer will result in a value one less than you expect.

Comment: "the length of an array is not stored anywhere at all; you have to keep track of it yourself." - it should be clarified that this only refers to arrays allocated via `malloc` and friends.  The length of named arrays is available via the array's name at any time.